# updating a table based on condition results from another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to find out what is wrong with my sql statement below. I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "P1Totals.StudentTotals" could not be bound

What am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE StudentRegistration
  SET Year ='2016',
  Term = 'Term 1'
where P1Totals.StudentTotals >='300'
  and P1Totals.StudentTotals <='400'
```

Comment: You have a reference to a table alias, `P1Totals`, but that table is not mentioned anywhere.  It is impossible to tell from the query what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results, along with a tag of the database you are using would help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgre? Oracle? And why do you store numbers as `varchar`?

Comment: In T-SQL (MS, Sybase) you could try and use [`UPDATE ... FROM...`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx). Note that you will probably have to join on some student id in both tables.

Comment: am using sql server 2008, i have two tables, studentregistration contains student data while p1totals contains student exam scores. i am trying to update the studentregistration table for all students whose total exam scores in the p1totals table lie between 300 and 400.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `P1Totals.` because its not mentioned as table alias.
In single update statement you can't give table alias.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
UPDATE StudentRegistration 
SET Year ='2016',
Term = 'Term 1'
from StudentRegistration
left join P1Totals on --your reference
where P1Totals.StudentTotals >='300'
and P1Totals.StudentTotals <='400'
```